# Is the term "Dead bodies" incorrect?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, redundancy, pleonasms

Recently, a guest faculty at our college delivered a lecture on the most commonly made errors in English. He pointed out the following sentence:

> There were 5 dead bodies.

He said that the above sentence is incorrect and it should be:

> There were 5 bodies.

As **body** is implying that the person is already dead, so there is no need to mention it explicitly.

So, is the first sentence incorrect?

Comment: @Josh *one* of the meanings.

Comment: 'There were 5 bodies' would very often contextually be interpreted as meaning corpses. However, the semantics doesn't demand this. And in any case, redundancy is trumped by usage. Anyone claiming this to be 'an error' is best ignored. An inferior style choice on occasion, maybe.

Comment: Even if it were redundant, it's not "wrong".  It might easily be said for effect, even if the meaning would be clear without "dead".

Comment: "Over my dead body" is a standard phrase, meaning "I am completely opposed to whatever is being discussed". "Over my body" would be meaningless in the same context.

Comment: My body is telling me right now that it is not dead. But what does it know?

Comment: "*As body is implying that the person is already dead*". Wrong. Is that what the dictionary told you?

Comment: Over at TV Tropes, this is known as the [Department of Redundancy Department](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DepartmentOfRedundancyDepartment). My favourite example of this phenomenon is the title of the 1976 Doctor Who serial "The Deadly Assassin".

Comment: Not necessarily redundant, depending on context.  For instance, a tropical beach might be described as so covered with bodies that the sand was hidden, but it's likely that few if any of them would be dead.

Comment: In "The Adventure of the Clapham Cook," Chief Inspector Japp needs a search warrant to open a trunk, which is in the train station in Glasgow.  Japp has just received a phone call from Sergeant Henry, who has located the trunk.Poirot  assures Japp that there is a body in the trunk and Japp assures Sergeant Henry that it is a dead body.

Comment: What was the content this guest lecturer was talking about?  Offhand, I'd say don't pay him any attention because he's an idiot, but it depends greatly on the content of his lecture.  If you're in a space-limited environment (such as a newspaper), you have to make tough calls regarding "extra" words like "dead" in this sentence.  He may have been talking to that.  140 character limit perhaps?

Comment: There can be 'warm bodies', 'hot bodies', 'hard bodies', and I don't want to work through whatever an exhaustive list might be. I'm pretty sure none of those bring thoughts of 'dead'. And when I read "As their bodies pressed together, she...", I can guarantee that I don't imagine corpses.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The usage 'dead body' is not incorrect. Though the word 'body' can be a synonym of 'dead body', it does not have always the meaning 'dead body'. 
From the MW:

**body** (plural bodies)
Learner's definition of BODY

1[count]

a: a person's or animal's whole physical self

```
the human body
a part of the body
Her body is very muscular.
A bird's body is covered in feathers.
```

— often used before another noun

```
body weight/fat
body parts
A person's normal body temperature [=(Brit) blood heat] is 98.6 degrees Fahrenheit or 37 degrees Celsius.
```

b 
: a dead person or animal

```
The body [=corpse] was shipped home for burial.
```

c 
: the main physical part of a person or animal

```
This species has a black body and a white head.
She held her arms tightly against her body.
```

So 'body' can be a live body too!

Comment: I've even heard phrases such as "putting bodies in seats," which refers to _live_ people sitting in those seats working at some job.

Comment: @DavidK Not necessarily live...

Answer (score 14):

*One* of the meanings of "body" is "corpse". As it can also mean "torso" or even "person", it's only redundant if the "dead" aspect can be inferred from context. Without context the example sentence has no redundancy and is perfectly correct. If there was some context to set up the meaning, it would still be perfectly grammatical - redundancy of this type is a matter of style not grammar.  "Dead corpses" would be completely redundant and is unidiomatic, but "dead bodies" is in common use.

[An arbitrarily-selected dictionary (Cambridge)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/body) has over a dozen definitions for body as a noun (some quite close), so it would seem reasonable to risk redundancy rather than ambiguity.